# Is there any official list of people that Zoro had captured or killed as a pirate hunter?

Tags: one-piece

I am wondering, since we all knew from the beginning when Zoro appears in the OP world, he was known as a "Bounty hunter" sometimes called "Pirate hunter Zoro".

Is there any official list of individuals that Zoro had captured or killed when he had that title?

Comment: I don't believe they ever released such a list.

Comment: His title is fictional as well, is that so?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that, but if you can expand on it a bit. You could ask it as a new question.

Comment: Specifically, I want to know the People zoro had captured/killed (pirates perhaps) when he was not in the mugiwara's crew. Since he was said to be a famous pirate hunter, and thus I'm wondering what makes him famous? If he had kill/captured a high bounty pirate then that would do.

Comment: I was reffering to your title comment. As for your question, see my answer

Comment: I'm sure this guy counts but don't know his name.  Sorry that it is a youtube link. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-6GfNznc2I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no known list of pirates Zoro captured or killed during his pirate hunter period. The only known one would be Mr. 7

> Zoro learned of Dracule "Hawk-Eye" Mihawk, who currently holds the title of the Greatest Swordsman in the world. He set off to sea, searching for him in order to challenge him to a duel. However, he lost his way, and could not find his way back home. In order to survive on his own, he took on bounties to pay for living expenses. He quickly built a famous reputation for himself as a "Pirate Hunter" in East Blue and even in Grand Line as Baroque Works had heard about him; he was even considered the greatest swordsman of East Blue, after which he met the two bounty hunters, Johnny and Yosaku.
>
> Because of his reputation as a bounty hunter, Zoro was offered a position as a numbered agent within the Baroque Works. He replied with that he would accept only on the condition that he would lead the organization (which they refused). He then killed Mr. 7, the agent who offered him the position, to defend himself. [- One Piece Wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Roronoa_Zoro/History)